# Regular expression for nnn or nnn.nnn

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
"^([0-9]{1,3})+(\.[0-9]{3})?$"
```

and it should allow only n, nn, nnn and nnn.nnn format of the number.

In my case it is passing also and this format nnnnn.nnn

Comment: The quotes are apparently not part of the regex; if you do have them where they should not be, that's part of the problem.

Comment: the central `+` must be the cause.

Comment: "^([0-9]{1,3})(\.[0-9]{3})?$"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove `+` and redundant parentheses:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})?$
 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your pattern matches start of the string (`^`), 1 or more occurrences of 1 to 3 digits (with  `([0-9]{1,3})+`) and an optional sequence of a dot followed with 3 digits (`(\.[0-9]{3})?`) at the end of the string (`$`).

The `[0-9]{1,3}` will only match 1 to 3 digits.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aW2bY9/1).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the 1 from the expression like : `^([0-9]{3})+(\.[0-9]{3})?$`

Answer (score 0):

The `+` after the first parenthesis allows for an arbitrary number of repeats.  If you mean `{1,3}` then you don't need the `+` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replay.That was the problem and I also removed the parenthesis from this ([0-9]{1,3}) to be like this [0-9]{1,3} and it works perfectly now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the `+` you have in the middle of your regex.

This means "one or more of the preceding element", thus it effectively means `1 one more ([0-9]{1,3}) and it must end with ([0-9]{3})?$`